Tooltip taking more time to render in .Net MAUI Mac catalsyt
I've been using Tooltip text with some views, but it's taking a considerable amount of time to render initially. However, after the first rendering, it works perfectly. Sometimes, it doesn't appear for a longer period, but when I unfocus and refocus the app, it starts to appear again.
Code snippet
ToolTipProperties.SetText(customView, "CustomView");
I am using it in .Net MAUI Maccatalyst.
It should render with minimum time with user response.

You may also try this, cocoa tooltip delay per object?.

You could try setting the NSInitialToolTipDelay using the following code,
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

#if MACCATALYST
    NSUserDefaults nSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
    NSObject nSObject = new NSNumber(100);
    NSString nSString = new NSString("NSInitialToolTipDelay");
    nSUserDefaults.SetValueForKey(nSObject, nSString);
#endif
    ...

From the above code, I set the render time to 0.1 second (100 millisecond).
For more info, you may refer to Invoke platform code.

But this will store this key value pair in local storage only, how can I use this with tooltip?

What's the meaning of use this with tooltip?
